# avr-gcc not seeing "const" modifier with PROGMEM

Tags: c, gcc, avr, avr-gcc

I have a file like this:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

const PROGMEM char* str = "Hello UART!\r\n";
```

I'm trying to compile it with a Makefile, this is the final command:

```
avr-gcc -std=gnu99 -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000UL -I. -Ilib/
    -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums
    -Wall -Wno-main -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-comment -g2 -Wextra
    -Wfatal-errors -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -ffunction-sections
    -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--relax -Os main.c lib/uart.c
    --output main.elf
```

I am getting the following error:

```
main.c:9:21: error: variable 'str' must be const in order to be put into read-only section by means of '__attribute__((progmem))'
 const PROGMEM char* str = "Hello UART!\r\n";
                     ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
Makefile:71: recipe for target 'main.elf' failed
make: *** [main.elf] Error 1
```

What's wrong with my code?

I tried moving the `PROGMEM` keyword in various places of the declaration, without any change.

Comment: Try: const char str[] PROGMEM = "Hello UART!\r\n";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const char str[] PROGMEM = "Hello UART!\r\n";
```

should work. You're creating a non-const pointer to const data.

Comment: will this put the \0 at the end, too?

Comment: Yes it will 0 terminate the string.

Comment: I still don't really understand the difference, but this works. Maybe you could try to add some more info? I always thought array is the same as pointer in c.

Comment: const char str[] PROGMEM = "Hello UART!\r\n"; declares a const array of 14 bytes (including 0 termination) to be put in program memory. const PROGMEM char* str = "Hello UART!\r\n";  only declares a non-const pointer to be put in program memory pointing to const data not in program memory. The non-const pointer cannot be put in program memory and therefore gives you the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code declares a non-`const` pointer to a(n array of) `const char`.  That is, the compiler is exactly right that variable `str` is non-`const`, it is the thing to which it points that is declared `const`.  If you want both pointer and pointed-to array to be `const`, then that would be this:

```
const PROGMEM char* const str = "Hello UART!\r\n";
```

or equivalently, this:

```
PROGMEM char const * const str = "Hello UART!\r\n";
```

Those two mean exactly the same thing as each other.